# Can other Debian based distributions use Ubuntu's repositories?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ubuntu has 4 repositories which are main, restricted, universe and multiverse. If i use another Debian-based distro, can I use these repositories?

Comment: Mint might (IDK for sure). If you're thinking of ditching Ubuntu bc of the snaps fiasco, it might be easier to just purge `snapd` instead.

Comment: in general purpose yes ; but I currently not see why doing that ? can you consider editing your question with a specific need

Comment: _Which_ other Debian-based Linux distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes... sort of.  It's not advised.  Adding different sections (e.g. `multiverse`, `universe`, `main`, `non-free`) isn't a problem.  The problem is related to the suite (e.g. `buster`, `bionic`, `tessa`, `kali-rolling`).

---

Be extremely careful when mixing software from different suites.  Always double-check the `apt` output before agreeing to install anything.  A worst-case scenario is that you try to upgrade something, it half-upgrades, but runs into version conflicts on your system and you wind up with a broken system.

[Pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration) gives you fine control over the versions of everything, but the Wiki starts by saying:

> With a few exceptions (DebianBackports) it is not recommended to mix repositories/releases unless they were specially prepared . Don't enable DebianUnstable repositories on DebianStable. When pinning, you must ensure compatibility of packages by yourself since Debian does not guarantee it.

---

It's also worth mentioning Debian's advice on this entitled "[Don't make a FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian)"

> Debian Stable should not be combined with other releases. If you're trying to install software that isn't available in the current Debian Stable release, it's not a good idea to add repositories for other Debian releases. The problems might not happen right away, but the next time you install updates.
>
> The reason things can break is because the software packaged for one Debian release is built to be compatible with the rest of the software for that release. For example, installing packages from bullseye on a buster system could also install newer versions of core libraries including libc6. This results in a system that is not testing or stable but a broken mix of the two.
>
> Repositories that can create a FrankenDebian if used with Debian Stable:
>
> - Debian testing release (currently bullseye)
> - Debian unstable release (also known as sid)
> - Ubuntu, Mint or other derivative repositories are not compatible with Debian!
> - Ubuntu PPAs

---

That said.  Here's how to do it!  Let's say you're on Debian `buster` and want a `multiverse` package from Ubuntu.  First think about which suite you want to pull from.  `buster` released in June 2019, so the [closest ubuntu release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) would be `disco` (April 2019).  That probably has the fewest differences.  Add an Ubuntu line to `/etc/apt/sources.list` like so:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
```

Before using `apt update` it's important to set the default-release so that the entire system doesn't accidentally switch to Ubuntu.  Add `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00local` with the following:

```
APT::Default-Release "buster";
```

Now apt knows that it will always use the versions found in `buster` before the versions found in `disco` unless explicitly specified.  Now it's safe to `apt update` to get the index of what's available in `disco`.

If you want to download a package from `disco` you can:

```
sudo apt install -t disco <package>
```

---

The problem comes when you start to mix different generations of releases. Other distros are often a snapshot of debian `unstable`, or a downstream equivalent.  These distros then add/replace a few (or many) packages to provide customization specific to that distro.

Ubuntu `xenial`, `bionic`, `focal`, or `groovy` are all snapshots of this repository at different points in time and so dependencies might be different.  Packages in `focal` work well with each other in general, but packages in `focal` may not work well with packages in `groovy` because they may depend on different versions of the same package.

If you are on mint `tara`, `tessa`, `tina`, or `tricia`, these were mostly [based on Ubuntu](https://www.linuxmint.com/download_all.php) `bionic`, so you'll want to pull from that suite if applicable.

Comment: There are other risks: the `groovy` package could have dependencies which are satisfied (as far as `apt` is aware) by Buster packages, but they might not really – in particular the GCC libraries (`libgcc`, `libstdc++`) and the C library itself are maintained separately, they don’t come from “snapshots of this repository at different points in time”. The combination hasn’t been tested...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think i'll settle for snap packages as they are "isolated" when it comes to installing packages from other distros. They don't interact with any of the packages in the system and thus have no dependencies